# wants to remove cdh4(hadoop) from ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, uninstall, hadoop

i have installed cdh3 pseudo mode in my ubuntu 12.04(precise) system using the following web reference

[cdh3-install-ubuntu12.04](http://varunkumarmanohar.blogspot.in/2013/06/cdh3-hadoop-installation-on-ubuntu-1204.html)

now i tried to install cdh4 to replace cdh3 but,unfortunately found that cdh4 only support 64bit in ubuntu version during the half way pf the cdh4 installation.so tried to remove cdh4 and installed cdh3 using the above link, during`sudo apt-get install hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo` i am getting the following error.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo : 
  Depends: hadoop-hdfs-namenode (= 2.0.0+1367-1.cdh4.3.1.p0.69~precise-cdh4.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: hadoop-hdfs-datanode (= 2.0.0+1367-1.cdh4.3.1.p0.69~precise-cdh4.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode (= 2.0.0+1367-1.cdh4.3.1.p0.69~precise-cdh4.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker (= 2.0.0+1367-1.cdh4.3.1.p0.69~precise-cdh4.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker (= 2.0.0+1367-1.cdh4.3.1.p0.69~precise-cdh4.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

i think this is because of chd4 partial installation, so i just want to remove entire cdh(hadoop) on my machine. So please help me to completely remove `cdh(cloudrea)hadoop` from my machine.

----(sep- 03-2013)---------------

while cdh4 installation, i have added gnu public key for cdh4 (curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cdh/archive.key | sudo apt-key 
add -). I think this would have causing me for the problem. if you know please tell me how to remove the public key from curl or modify that for cdh3.......

Answer (score 1):

I don't  know if you'll like this answer but you can try `apt-get purge hadoop-0.20-*`, to clean everything up including config files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JtheRocker .i tried your solution but when i am trying **sudo apt-get install hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo** i am getting the same error.i think ** gnu-public license key ** for cdh4 is the cause for this problem.don't know how to remove or modify the curl public key for cdh3 in ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Hi I resolved by just removing cdh4 files from the source of

> etc/apt/sources.list.d